# Why the values of Base Pay, Taxes etc are not returning

Tags: c

I am running into an issue where it can compile properly but the values of base pay, etc any of the calculation lines of code are not printing in the print employee functions. I am suspecting that I need to return those values to the function but I am not sure how to do so. Do I change void to something like float? Do I leave the parameters as it is or do I have to change those too. Thanks!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Employee
{
   char Name[20];
   float HoursWorked;
   float HourlyRate;
   float BasePay;
   float OverTimePay;
   float GrossPay;
   float Taxes;
   float NetPay;
}EmployeeInput;



float Menu(struct Employee EmployeeInput[]);

float Prompts(struct Employee EmployeeInput[]);

void PayRoll(struct Employee EmployeeInput[]);

void TotalNTax(struct Employee EmployeeInput[]);

void Updating(struct Employee EmployeeInput[]);

void PrintingOneEmployee(struct Employee EmployeeInput[]);

void PrintingAllEmployees(struct Employee EmployeeInput[]);




 float Prompts(struct Employee EmployeeInput[])
 {
    char UserInput; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       printf("Name:  \n");
       scanf("%s", EmployeeInput[i].Name);
       if (strcmp(EmployeeInput[i].Name, "-1") == 0)
       {
           break;
       }
       printf("Hours Worked: \n");
       scanf("%f",&EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked);
       if (EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked == -1)
       {
           break;
       }
       printf("Hourly Wage:  \n");
       scanf("%f",&EmployeeInput[i].HourlyRate);
       if (EmployeeInput[i].HourlyRate == -1)
       {
           break;
       }
       scanf("%c", &UserInput);
   }
   return 0;
}



void Updating(struct Employee EmployeeInput[])
{
   int Number;
   printf("Who would you like to edit? \n");
   printf("1. %s\n", EmployeeInput[0].Name);
   printf("2.%s\n ", EmployeeInput[1].Name);
   printf("3.%s\n ", EmployeeInput[2].Name);
   printf("4.%s\n ", EmployeeInput[3].Name);
   printf("5.%s\n ", EmployeeInput[4].Name);
 
   scanf("%d", &Number);
   printf("Enter the New Name: \n");
   scanf("%s",EmployeeInput[Number].Name);
   printf("Enter New Amount of Hours: \n");
   scanf("%f", &EmployeeInput[Number].HoursWorked);
   printf("Enter New Hourly Rate: \n");
   scanf("%f", &EmployeeInput[Number].HourlyRate);
}



float Menu(struct Employee EmployeeInput[])
{  
   int Choice;
   int x =1;
   while ( x = 1)
  {
     printf("1. Update an existing employee\n");
     printf("2. Print One Employee \n");
     printf("3. Print All Employees \n");
     printf("4. Quit \n");
     scanf("%d", &Choice);


     switch(Choice) 
     {
         case 1:
         Updating(EmployeeInput);
         break;
    
         case 2: 
         PrintingOneEmployee(EmployeeInput);
         break;
    
         case 3: 
         PrintingAllEmployees(EmployeeInput);
         break;

         case 4: 
         return 0;
     }
    }
  }

void PayRoll(struct Employee EmployeeInput[])
 {
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      if(EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked < 40)
      {
           EmployeeInput[i].BasePay = EmployeeInput[i].HourlyRate * 
           EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked;
           EmployeeInput[i].GrossPay = EmployeeInput[i].BasePay;
           EmployeeInput[i].OverTimePay = 0;
       }
       else if(EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked > 40)
       {
           float overtimehours = EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked - 40;
           EmployeeInput[i].OverTimePay = (overtimehours * EmployeeInput[i].HourlyRate) 
           * 1.5;
           EmployeeInput[i].BasePay = (EmployeeInput[i].HourlyRate * 
           EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked) - EmployeeInput[i].OverTimePay;
           EmployeeInput[i].GrossPay = EmployeeInput[i].BasePay + 
           EmployeeInput[i].OverTimePay;
        }
    }
}



  void TotalNTax(struct Employee EmployeeInput[])
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       EmployeeInput[i].Taxes = EmployeeInput[i].GrossPay * 0.2;
       EmployeeInput[i].NetPay = EmployeeInput[i].GrossPay - EmployeeInput[i].Taxes;
    }
 }



int main()
{
    struct Employee EmployeeNumber[5];
    Prompts(EmployeeNumber);
    Menu(EmployeeNumber);
    PayRoll(EmployeeNumber);

}



void PrintingOneEmployee(struct Employee EmployeeInput[])
{
    int Number; 
    printf("Please enter the number of the employee you wish to print.");
    printf("1. %s\n", EmployeeInput[0].Name); 
    printf("2. %s\n", EmployeeInput[1].Name);
    printf("3. %s\n", EmployeeInput[2].Name);
    printf("4. %s\n ", EmployeeInput[3].Name);
    printf("5. %s\n ", EmployeeInput[4].Name);
    scanf("%d", &Number);
    printf("Name: %s\n", EmployeeInput[Number].Name);
    printf("Hours worked: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[Number].HoursWorked);
    printf("Hourly rate: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[Number].HourlyRate);
    printf("Base pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[Number].BasePay);
    printf("Overtime pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[Number].OverTimePay);
    printf("Gross pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[Number].GrossPay);
    printf("Taxes paid: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[Number].Taxes);
    printf("Net pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[Number].NetPay);
}



  void PrintingAllEmployees(struct Employee EmployeeInput[])
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  printf("Name: %s\n", EmployeeInput[i].Name);
  printf("Hours worked: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked);
  printf("Hourly rate: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[i].HourlyRate);
  printf("Base pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[i].BasePay);
  printf("Overtime pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[i].OverTimePay);
  printf("Gross pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[i].GrossPay);
  printf("Taxes paid: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[i].Taxes);
  printf("Net pay: %0.2f\n", EmployeeInput[i].NetPay);
  }
}
```

Comment: `while ( x = 1)` doesn't do what you think.  But that's not your bug.

Comment: To be clear, `while (x=1)` is an endless loop. You want `while (x==1)`

Comment: I don't think you actually use the return values for anything. I would expect maybe `static float get_number(void)` or better `bool get_number(float *)`.

Comment: Which "print employee" function are you referring to?

Comment: Harvey Yang, Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: Save your eyes.  Instead of `EmployeeInput[i].HoursWorked`, do something like `struct Employee *e = EmployeeInput + i; e->HoursWorked ...`